# What is coredata equivalent for android

Tags: android, core-data

I used to program for iPhone.

But then I want to make another similar program in Android.

Well, should I use a coredata like framework?

Does android have something similar?

Comment: this is an old question. In 2015 , you can have a look at realm.io  https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: also take a look at https://github.com/dkharrat/NexusData

Comment: Check out [JDXA](http://www.softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/jdxa.html), a simple, non-intrusive, and flexible ORM for Android.

Comment: It would seem that **realm.io** is really "the" solution these days - indeed for both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Actually what you need is to check ORM tools for Android for persistence.And decide on which one suits you best.

Here are your top choices:

OrmLite : http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml

GreenDao : http://greendao-orm.com/

Comment: My voteup is for Green-DAO, but all should keep in mind about migration issues, which is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046258/what-is-coredata-equivalent-for-android

Comment: I checked `OrmLite`, but it can not modify records in a weak-type way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890602/get-dao-with-weak-typing-in-ormlite

Comment: Room Data Storage is a new way to store application data in Android. It is provided by google and is a part of the Android Architecture components. Room is offered as a high-level, first-party alternative to Realm, ORMLite, GreenDao and many others.

Answer (score 12):

`Room` Data Storage is a new way to store application data in Android. It is provided by google and is a part of the Android Architecture components. `Room` is offered as a high-level, first-party alternative to `Realm`, `ORMLite`, `GreenDao` and many others.

Answer (score 5):

I recently released an open source version of Core Data for Android, called NexusData. You can find it here: https://github.com/dkharrat/NexusData

It's still early in development, but hopefully will mature over time.

Answer (score 5):

Try Android Realm. It looks straight forward and easy to use

https://github.com/realm/realm-java

Comment: Realm is good and had been a good choice for most of my projects. Just keep in mind that working with Realm and [multiple processes (threads)](https://academy.realm.io/posts/threading-deep-dive/) may produce unexpected transaction errors if you don't take all precautions.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think that you have two solutions to save data without using directly SQLite.

You can use shared preference to save a value to a key. It permits to save information quickly, but it's quite limited. 
Also, I have heard about **greenDAO** (read the ["get started"](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/how-to-get-started/)), unfortunately it will be harder to use than **Core Data** because you will not find any user interface.

Comment: That's good enough. greenDAO. Is this the best? What is this?

Comment: I know this is old, but I wanted to respond that I am currently trying out greenDAO and it generates the SQL statements for you and wraps them in class so you can use them easier and without making typo's in your queries