# Get DAO with weak-typing in OrmLite?

Tags: java, android, orm, ormlite

Is it possible to get the corresponding Dao in `OrmLite`, without passing class name to `createDao`, **without a static type-checking**?

```
Dao<Account, String> accountDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Account.class);
```

But insert or update record by passing table / attribute name as string?

Do you know any `Orm` available for Android, can do this?

Comment: Well, if you don't want to create one separate DAO for each model class, you can check JDXA ORM. Here are some JDXA code snippets: http://softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/code-snippets.html.  I don't understand what you mean by "insert or update record by passing table name as string"

Comment: In iOS ORM called `Core Data` system evaluate in runtime which table / field need to modify, without any type check. Web service can send a JSON and so order client to update table "A"  on field "c", but table "B" on field "d" is also possible, without compile time check wether specified table and field exist at all in the DB. It is powerful because you can make code more loose-coupled.

Comment: Well, JDXA does not make any compile time check for the existence of any underlying tables. Of course, as part of initialization, any needed tables would be created when the app is run for the first time. The JDXA insert and update methods take an object or a collection of objects as parameters and dynamically determine which table(s) the object(s) will be persisted in.